# How to recognize a compilation is first-time-build or refresh in wepack compile hook 'done'?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5, webpack-plugin

I want to collect the build speeds of our project for advancing performance optimization. The indexes include `build-speed, devServer-start-speed, and devServer-refresh-speed`:

- build-speed: the speed when run `webpack build` in cli
- devServer-start-speed: the speed that start devServer
- devServer-refresh-speed: the speed when devServer refresh/hot-update

My plan is to write a `webpack plugin` with [compile hook done](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#done) to collect these indexes.(webpack 5)

The done hook provides a param `stats` for callback fn, and I can calculate the build speeds by  `startTime` and `endTime` in the `stats object`.

But it seems that there is no more info that can distinguish the current compilation is the first-time build or refresh.(we use `@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin` to optimize the build speed).

Any idea to recognize a compilation is first-time-build or refresh?

Below is my plugin:

```js
class BuildStatsWebpackPlugin {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap({ name: 'BuildStatsWebpackPlugin' }, (stats) => {
      const startTime = stats.compilation.startTime;
      const endTime = stats.compilation.endTime;
      const speed = endTime - startTime;

      const buildType = ''; // how to get the type from stats?

      report({
        buildType,
        speed
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Besides, is there an interface declaration of `Stats`?

Answer (score 1):

I also need to distinguish between first compilation and recompilation, and found nothing in webpack docs.

I need it to decide if I should run a script using `hook-shell-script-webpack-plugin`, here's what I came up with:

```
    new HookShellScriptPlugin({
      thisCompilation: [
        (compilation, compilationParams) => {
          console.log('==================');
          if (compilationParams.contextModuleFactory.resolverFactory.cache.size === 0) {
            console.log('FIRST GENERATION');
            return 'yarn myscript';
          } else {
            console.log('REGENERATION');
          }
          console.log('==================');
        },
      ],
    }),
```

I'm not sure if and how is it applicable to your situation, but that's the way of solving the problem inside webpack config, using webpack hooks.

It doesn't look like a proper way to solve a problem, but it works for me.

Comment: kind of hacking but it works, thx!

Comment: besides, had you tried to distinguish between first-time compilation with cache and without cache?  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/